# Sum operation syntax error

Tags: python, math, syntax

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
        print('print("Hello world '+ str (i*9)+'")')
        i = i + 1
```

I was practicing loop and I wonder why I have to put + after `STR(1*9) ?? 
 print('print("Hello world '+ str (i*9)'")')` and Why this code has syntax error?
(no plus sign)
I tried put code `print(print("Hello world"+str(i*9)))` to not use + but I got

> Hello world0
>
> None
>
> Hello world9
>
> None
>
> Hello world18
>
> None

Comment: What is the **strong text** supposed to be? It surely is not a comment in python...

Comment: @mrCarnivore it's the SO default **strong text**. I don't think it was in the original code.

Comment: Why do you add "print(" in a print statement? Do you really mean to print out "print(Hello World" ?

Comment: yes i mean to print out "print("hello world") but i'm just curious why i have to put str (i*9)+ not str(i*9)

Comment: What does this have to do with math?  This is about string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To concatenate two string together you need the `+` operator to tell the python interpreter to specify its `some_string` **plus** `some_other_string`.

Alternatively if you dont like using the `+` operator you can use `.format()` like so;

```
while i < 10:
    print("Hello World {0}".format(i*9))
    i = i + 1
```

The string to be inserted goes inside the curly braces. I used 0 inside the curlies because you can add others to your string incrementing the numbers and adding another paramater to the `format` function.

Answer (score 0):

A + concatenates strings in python. So you need it. Python does not know how to interpret two variables next to each other without , or + or else between them. '")' is also considered a variable in programming context.

Comment: Sorry if you read it that way. But that is a true question to the person who asked the question. What should python do in that case? It cannot know that it should concatenate since it is just two strings next to each other...

Comment: If it is a question (and I didn't down vote you btw) then you can request clarification in the comments. If you do not have the rep to comment, you'll just have to wait till you can.